# Hide image on click of button and show text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery(".b2b-btn").click(function() {

  jQuery(".b2b-image").removeClass('hideb2bimage');
  jQuery(".b2b-text").removeClass('expanded');

  jQuery(this).closest('col-b2b').find(".b2b-image").toggleClass('hideb2bimage');
  jQuery(this).closest('col-b2b').find(".b2b-text").toggleClass('expanded');


});
```

```css
.hideb2bimage {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.b2b-text {
  height: 0px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s ease-out 500ms, opacity 500ms;
}

.expanded {
  height: auto;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s ease-in 0s, opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-row">
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" scr="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" scr="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" scr="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show text and hide image upon clicking on the button. But I only want to show the text of the column which button is clicked.  Also in case someone click on the first column and it shows the text of one column and then click on the second column button it should hide the text of first column. Above is the code I am using please let me know what mistake I am making. Also I want to make click function on image as well.

Comment: please add `.main-row` `.col-b2b` css, I'm lost

Comment: there is no CSS for those.

Comment: if there is no CSS for those, then `.col-b2b` elements are not columns. why do you describe them as columns ?

Comment: I just have to give them a class name or something to mentioned that is is column. Basically I am doing this in WordPress and html css code there is different so just to make it simple and describe my issue I use this html.

Comment: `scr=` ? you mean `src=` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".b2b-btn").click(function() {
    var btn = $(this);
    var img = btn.parent().find("img");
    var txt = btn.parent().find("p");
    var state = txt.hasClass("expanded");
    $(".main-row .b2b-text").removeClass("expanded");
    $(".main-row .b2b-image").removeClass("hideb2bimage");
    if (state) {
      img.removeClass("hideb2bimage");
      txt.removeClass("expanded");
    } else {
      img.addClass("hideb2bimage");
      txt.addClass("expanded");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.col-b2b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
}

.hideb2bimage {
  display: none;
}

.b2b-text {
  display: none;
}

.expanded {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-row">
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `.toggleClass()` can be really helpful in these use cases.

> **Description:** Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the state argument.

https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

**Update**

I am better able to understand your need. I have updated the code above to help determine the current state of the Text. If it's expanded, collapse it. But for all, collapse the text and show the image regardless of the button that is clicked.

Comment: @MisterJojo upon inspection they have 0 for height and width. Not sure if it's SO Snippet. Might rebuild in JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is still not resolved. What I want is when someone click on button1 it should hide image and show text which its doing but if someone also click on the second button it should hide the text of the first column and show back the image and then hide the image of second column and show the text

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef do you want all images to no longer be visible or to be hidden?

Comment: Other images should be visible. What I want it should only hide the image and show the text of the column which button is clicked. In case someone click the button in Colmn1 and then click the column2 button then first column should go back to its original state and it should hide the image of second column and show its text.

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef updated.

Comment: not working please check this website last section before footer. See what's happening http://bodyscent.brandnew.ie/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238044/discussion-between-muhammad-tauseef-and-twisty).

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef check out the code updates. I think I understand what you want now. Your code may be a bit different due to the more complex structure WP uses. The basics are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Several typos and some css mistakes:

- `jQuery(this).closest('col-b2b')` should be `jQuery(this).closest('.col-b2b')`.
- `<img class="b2b-image" scr="` should be `<img class="b2b-image" src="`.
- `visibility`cannot be transformed. Use `opacity` instead.
- `height` and other lengths cannot be transformed to `auto` values. Work with animating `max-height` instead.

```js
jQuery(".b2b-btn").click(function() {
  jQuery(".b2b-image").removeClass('hideb2bimage');
  jQuery(".b2b-text").removeClass('expanded');
  jQuery(this).closest('.col-b2b').find(".b2b-image").toggleClass('hideb2bimage');
  jQuery(this).closest('.col-b2b').find(".b2b-text").toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

```css
.b2b-image {
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.hideb2bimage {
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.b2b-text {
  height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.expanded {
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-row">
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3">
    <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    <button class="b2b-btn">Please Click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the typo that is not the issue. Issue is javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion with smooth transition without any flickering:

- **Fix** the images attribute `scr` to `src`
- **Create a common wrapper DIV** `.b2b-cont` for the text and the image
- Set the **image as an absolute** underlay, almost as a background image
- Use **CSS Flex** so that the text length dictates the boxes height
- Just **toggle with JS** a class like `.is-active` from the **closest** column parent. **Remove** `.is-active` from all the other columns

Example:

```js
jQuery(($) => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

  $(".b2b-btn").on("click", function() {
    const $col = $(this).closest(".col-b2b");
    const $otherCol = $(this).closest(".main-row").find(".col-b2b").not($col);
    $col.toggleClass("is-active");
    $otherCol.removeClass("is-active"); 
  });

});
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/ * {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.main-row {
  display: flex;
}

.col-b2b {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.b2b-cont {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.b2b-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.b2b-text {
  padding: 1em;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.col-b2b.is-active .b2b-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.col-b2b.is-active .b2b-image {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-row">
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <div class="b2b-cont">
      <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1">
      <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    </div>
    <button class="b2b-btn" type="button">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <div class="b2b-cont">
      <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=2">
      <p class="b2b-text">this is some text</p>
    </div>
    <button class="b2b-btn" type="button">Please Click</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b2b">
    <div class="b2b-cont">
      <img class="b2b-image" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=3">
      <p class="b2b-text">This text, since it's the longest, it dictates all other elements heights thanks to CSS flex. If you learn CSS flex there's no going back, you can only start to learn to cook, pet your cat, dry-leaf-jumping...</p>
    </div>
    <button class="b2b-btn" type="button">Please Click</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MuhammadTauseef you're welcome!